# Does the Qualcomm MDM 9207 chip have WiFi, Bluetooth and GPS?

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, gps, cellphone

I am researching about the Qualcomm MDM9207 chip and I have some questions regarding it:

1. Does this chip contains a WiFi module or do we have to integrate it outside?
2. Does this chip have a Bluetooth module or we have to integrate it?
3. Does this chip contain a GPS module or not?

I have researched this and I got some information regarding it but I am not sure whether this is contained in the chip or not.

This is the link: https://www.qualcomm.com/products/qualcomm-9207-lte-modem

Comment: What does the datasheet say? If you do not have a datasheet an NDA might be required to obtain it from Qualcomm. As an individual the chances that you get an NDA with Qualcomm are **zero**. Realize that in many of such SoCs, not all functionality is on this chip. Often support chips (especially for RF) are needed.

Answer (score 1):

It has an integrated Wi-Fi subsystem and a Bluetooth subsystem.

It doesn't come with a GPS subsystem.

As far as I understant, it's meant for system integrators like: Gemalto, Thales, uBlox

Answer (score 0):

[This is an information sheet from Qualcomm on the MDM9207.](https://www.qualcomm.com/media/documents/files/qualcomm-3g-4g-lte-iot-infographic.pdf)

From the second page:

> - Integrated global positioning support for GPS, Beidou, GLONASS, and Galileo
> - Small package at 28nm LP to allow for optimized IoT form factors
> - Pre-integrated support for Qualcomm® VIVE™ Wi-Fi 1x1, 802.11ac featuring Qualcomm® MU | EFX MU-MIMO technology and BT 4.1 BLE

That appears to say that it has GPS built in but that WiFi and Bluetooth require additional hardware.